# How to connect Url to GridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, url, odbc

I already connected the `sql` server using `odbc` connection.

```
    Using con As New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};Server=WJNJPHR8TCX8P\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Fabrics;Integrated Security=True;"),
  cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM [Client] WHERE [ClientID] = ? Or [FirstName] = ? OR [MiddleName] = ? OR [LastName] = ?", con)
        con.Open()

    End Using
```

I also establish the `Host`, `Path`, `Url`

```
        Dim host As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
        Dim path As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
        Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

And also establish the `NameValueCollection`

```
        Dim qscoll As NameValueCollection = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url)
```

For Example:

I type `http://localhost:21231/example.aspx?ClientId=13` and get the result set ClientId=13 displaying in `GridView`.

Question:

How can I connect the `Url` to `GridView`

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: do you have results in json form ?

Comment: No. I don't use json. @Idle001

Comment: so ???? what's separator for received data

Comment: I don't think I need separator for received data. All I need is to connect the `Url` to `GridView` but I don't know how to do it. :(

Comment: you can initiate a datatable and fill it with query output, [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1972053.aspx?How+do+I+convert+OdbcDataReader+to+DataTable+or+DataSet+) how you can do it